# Its possible to write Stored Procedure like stuff in Solr?

Tags: solr, solrj

Rather than executing complex queries with many parameters, its possible if to send parameters to Solr,and then Solr's handler(similar to Database's stored procedure) can handle all logical manipulations and return the json output.

I have found one reference :

http://blog.sematext.com/2014/04/29/parametrizing-queries-in-solr-and-elasticsearch/

But it doesn't talk about the programmatically manipulate the received input params, and then return the json.

Comment: Write a plugin https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Solr+Plugins

Answer (score 1):

During the update process, Solr supports many kind of scripting languages (Javascript, JRuby, Groovy, Jython).
To be clear, you can use those scripts only during the document update, not at query time.

http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/07/02/log-every-solr-doc/
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ScriptUpdateProcessor

If you want customise the search request/response, I know two ways:

1. write a web application which enquiries Solr, even more times, and then returns a customised response. In this case you could use many languages, even scripting languages like Javascript (nodejs), PHP, Phyton and more.
2. write a Solr plugin. But, given that write a Solr plugin is quite hard and you can do it only in Java, give a try to [Alba](https://github.com/leonardofoderaro/alba), which is a small Java framework that amis to simplify the development of Solr plugins.

Comment: Lets consider a small use case :Two fields - A.category B.Date-Time,  4 Queries are made based on a specific category A by hour,  A by Date , A by Month , A by Year. so backend hits four times to solr to get the result. Is there a way to club all these into one query ? ( as suggested - write a plugin) - else backend hit four queries to Solr, clubbed the four response into one, and return to fronted. Is there anything else you can suggest ?(serious and great thanks for your answer)